# How do i Change Column name as per the mapped sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 sheets named 'sheet1', 'sheet2' and 'mapping' sheet.

'Sheet1' consist the actual data (Can say raw data and column numbers/header name can be different)

'Sheet2' Consist the master sheet columns (Sheet1 data header should be as per the sheet2)

'mapping' consist the mapping between sheet1 and sheet2

I am looking for code which can update sheet1 columns as per the mapping sheet.
Like if mapping sheet says "AB" = "C1" then 'sheet1' column should be updated as "C1"

```
| AB| AF| AL|   | C1| C2| C3|   |sheet1 column_name |  Sheet2 column_name|
|-----------|   |-----------|   |     AB            |    C1              |
| 1 | f | y |   |   |   |   |   |     AL            |    C2              | 
|---------- |   |---------- |   |     AF            |    C3              | 
| 2 | g | Q |   |   |   |   |   -----------------------------------------
|---------- |   |---------- |   
| 6 | i | e |   |   |   |   |   
-------------   -------------   
       "Sheet 1"     "Sheet 2"                  "Mapping"
```

I have tried it using matchfunction but didn't get success.any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**`I am looking for code`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you're in a wrong place buddy.

Comment: there is always a way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following Code.. it may solve problem or give an idea.

```
Sub renameworksheetcolumnmatach()
Dim test, findtext  As Variant
Sheets("SHEET1").Activate
Dim i, j  As Integer
For i = 1 To 36
findtext = Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(1, i).Value
On Error Resume Next
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(findtext,     Sheets("MAPPING").Range("A1:A100"), 0) Then
Set rngx = Worksheets("mAPPING").Range("A1:A100").Find(findtext,                LookAt:=xlWhole)
c = rngx.Address
newcolval = Sheets("Interface").Range(c).Offset(0, 1).Value
If newcolval = "" Then
Cells(1, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
GoTo P
End If
Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(1, i) = newcolval
End If
P:
Next i
End Sub
```